# Get all filenames in folder with Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, filenames

I need a baisc method in Actionscript 3 to get an array with the filenames of all the files of a specific folder. The folder is located on my local WAMP (php) server. (http://localhost/flash/uploads/xml)

Do I als need php-code, or will it works with only AS3-code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can only do this on Adobe AIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regular Actionscript does not support file and directory commands in a good way. You would definitely be better off using something else.